# VB: Count number of columns in csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

So, quite simple.

I am importing CSVs into a datagrid, though the csv always has to have a variable amount of columns.

For 3 Columns, I use this code:

```
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader("E:\test.txt")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(";"c)
        dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)), _
                             New DataColumn(newline(1)), _
                             New DataColumn(newline(2))})
        While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
            newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(";"c)
            Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1), newline(2)}
            dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
        End While
        DG1.DataSource = dt
```

This works perfectly. But how do I count the number of "newline"s ?

Can I issue a count on the number of newlines somehow? Any other example code doesn't issue column heads.

If my csv file has 5 columns, I would need an `Addrange` of 5 instead of 3 and so on..

Thanks in advance

Comment: `newline.Count` or what are you asking for here?

Comment: I need to count the number of columns in my csv file, basically. Edited question.

Comment: Or perhaps you need something like a [For Each](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)...

Comment: `newline` is an array so it has a `Length`, which is the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
    ' MsgBox(newline.Count)
    ' dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)),
    '                     New DataColumn(newline(1)),
    '                    New DataColumn(newline(2))})
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To newline.Count - 1
        dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(i))})
    Next
    While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1)}
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
    End While
    dgv.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: if you notice the dt.columns.AddRange(...) in a comment section, which is the original code, the number of columns it counts is depends on how many array inside the .AddRange(...) What I did so it automatically get the number of columns is first, the newline.count, and since you already know the number of columns, you can now fo For loops for you to add the Newline(i) codes.

Comment: Great! It helps users to find their answer more quickly if you add that to your code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Columns and item values can be added to a `DataTable` individually, using [`dt.Columns.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hb99w3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`newrow.Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so that these can be done in a loop instead of hard-coding for a specific number of columns.  e.g. (this code assumes `Option Infer On`, so adjust as needed):

```
Public Function CsvToDataTable(csvName As String, Optional delimiter As Char = ","c) As DataTable
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    For Each line In File.ReadLines(csvName)
        If dt.Columns.Count = 0 Then
            For Each part In line.Split({delimiter})
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(part))
            Next
        Else
            Dim row = dt.NewRow()
            Dim parts = line.Split({delimiter})
            For i = 0 To parts.Length - 1
                row(i) = parts(i)
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(row)
        End If
    Next
    Return dt
End Function
```

You could then use it like:

```
Dim dt = CsvToDataTable("E:\test.txt", ";"c)
DG1.DataSource = dt
```